# PHP namespace for abstract class

Tags: php, namespaces

having issues with defining a namespace for an abstract class.
Class looks like so:

*helloworld.class.php*:

```
namespace Kitten;
abstract class HelloWorld {
    public static function hi()
    {
        echo 'hello';
    }
}
```

*index.php*:

```
require_once helloworld.class.php;
Kitten::HelloWorld::hi();
```

The error I'm getting is: `syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: btw, T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM means :: (double colon) in Hebrew.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Namespaces are accessed with the backslash character

`\Kitten\HelloWorld::hi();`

`T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` means double colon `::`, a [Scope Resolution Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

Your require statement is also incorrect. Wrap the file and path in quotes as follows:

```
require_once 'helloworld.class.php';
```

Comment: Alright. That seems to have done it. Internally in the hi class, I'm actually trying to call a different method statically that was already loaded. But it's trying to call it within the frame/context of the currently defined namespace. Any thoughts?

Comment: oh nice. I just prepend the classname with a forward slash (/). thanks all.